# JPA Cast Exception

Tags: java, database, oracle, jpa

I'm trying to build a db schema with Oracle and JPA. I'm new to JPA, I always worked directly with sql.
What I need to do create are two tables: the first one containing the current VOIP calls and another with the history of those calls. The two tables are identical.
In JPA I wrote this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "voip_currentCalls")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class VoipCurrentCall implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected CompositeID id;
    protected Timestamp startTime;
    protected Timestamp endTime;
    protected String calledNumber;
    protected String callingNumber;    
    protected Person contact;
    protected CallSource source;
    protected CallStatus status;
    protected CallType type;
    protected CallStage stage;

@Entity
@Table(name = "voip_historyCalls")
public class VoipHistoryCall extends VoipCurrentCall implements Serializable {
...
```

As you can see the second table has no other fields, but it is simply and extends of the first.
when I try to cast the VoipCurrentCall to VoipHistoryCall, I obtain java.lang.ClassCastException: VoipCurrentCall cannot be cast to VoipHistoryCall.

Have you any suggestions? I'm probably missing something.
Thank to all in advance!

Comment: You cannot cast a superclass to subclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if the object you are trying to cast is ***not*** a history call, then the cast will most assuredly fail. JPA entities are still bound to the same casting rules as regular Java objects. Case in point:

```
Object obj = new Object();
String str = (String) obj;
```

The above will yield a class cast exception at runtime, it doesn't matter if a String is an Object, if the Object isn't a String. As far as your JPA design, you actually should go about it slightly different. JPA provides some standard ways to define inheritance hierarchies. In your case, I would recommend using a `@MappedSuperclass`. Something like this:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseVoipCurrentCall implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private CompositeID id;

    private Timestamp startTime;
    private Timestamp endTime;
    private String calledNumber;
    private String callingNumber;    
    private Person contact;
    private CallSource source;
    private CallStatus status;
    private CallType type;
    private CallStage stage;

    // Constructors, getters/setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "voip_currentCalls")
public class VoipCurrentCall extends BaseVoipCurrentCall {
    // Voip current call specific attributes and logic
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "voip_historyCalls")
public class VoipHistoryCall extends BaseVoipCurrentCall {
    // Voip history call specific attributes and logic
}
```

Comment: Thank you very very much for your precious suggestion! My fist mistake was my stupidity forgetting java inheritance rules, giving all the fault to JPA (that for me are still a big obscure technology), but as you evidenced me there was also a design problem.

Answer (score 4):

It's the way Java is designed; you cannot cast a superclass to a subclass only the other way round. It doesn't have anything to do with JPA.

Comment: I was so much concentrated on JPA and netbeans doesn't give me evidence of my stupidity, so I suddenly thought it was a JPA problem! Pardon me!!